# Type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error in my global.aspx file

Error 1 The type arguments for method   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SalesERPDAL>());
    }

}
```

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'SalesERPDAL' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't get the errors, it was working until I got an error about The model backing the context has changed since the database was created.

What do I need to do to get it working ?

Comment: Is `SalesERPDAL` is the same namespace?  If not do you need to add a `using` directive?

Comment: got it thanks !!! didn't have the namespace

Comment: Glad it's working - since this is basically a typo I'm going to vote to close it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add generic argument with your context type to `SetInitializer` method:

```
Database.SetInitializer<SalesERPDAL>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SalesERPDAL>());
```

Comment: when I put that in it says I am missing a reference ? Error 1 The type or namespace name 'SalesERPDAL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\C#\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Global.asax.cs 27 37 WebApplication1

Comment: @Aindriu Add `using` to namespace containing `SalesERPDAL`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Write using statement at the top of the Global.asax file >> using System.Data.Entity; and using WebApplication1.DataAccessLayer;
I solved this problem by adding above two using statements.
It will drop the existing database and recreate the new database. But we will lose all data from old database. I face this problem :-(